# PayPal not returning any value

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to do PayPal integration with my website. However, I found that PayPal is not returning any value on my sandbox account when I complete the payment. I do some searching and I found this page (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments) which allows me to set 'Auto Return' and 'Payment Data Transfer' to ON. But after I save it and refresh the page, it shows OFF again. I feel that the page is old page because I can't find way to navigate to that page from PayPal interface.

Do you have any idea why PayPal doesn't return any value? How can I enable 'Auto Return' and 'Payment Data Transfer' in my sandbox account?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi halfer, thanks for your help. I found that it was caused by my WampServer error that it run into older version of PHP. So, I guess that question will no longer needed and it may bring confusion to others and I decided to delete it. Thank you.

Comment: OK. Ideally, if you can comment to that effect on a question, and delete a day later, it'll make it less likely that the post disappears whilst people are typing. Glad you fixed it, anyway `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to https://developer.paypal.com and login here.

Then click Enter sandbox site and login with default facilitator account.

Now click on profile tab of "my account" and you will see "Website payments preferences".

click on it and enable 'Auto Return' and 'Payment Data Transfer' in for sandbox account.